# How do I produce a barchart/histogram in R that orders by factor number but displays the factor names?

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart, label

I have data on mushroom edibility that looks like this:

```
SpeciesName         Edibility   EdibilityRank  
abruptibulbus       Good                    3  
arvensis            Choice                  1  
bisporus            Good                    3  
bitorquis           Choice                  1  
campestris          Choice                  1  
diminutivus         Presumed harmless       4  
fuscofibrillosus    Choice non-standard     2  
haemorrhoidarius    Choice non-standard     2  
micromegethus       Presumed harmless       4  
placomyces          Mildly poisonous        5  
silvaticus          Choice non-standard     2  
silvicola           Good                    3  
subrufescens        Choice                  1
```

For each species of mushroom (first column) there is an edibility descriptor (second column) and a numerical edibility ranking (third column) with the lower a ranking is, the more preferable the mushroom is. There is a one-to-one relationship between the descriptors and the rankings.

I want to produce a barchart/histogram that shows the frequency of each level of edibility, ordered by rank and labeled on the x-axis with the descriptor. In other words, although the edibility descriptor looks like a nominal/categorical variable, it's really a nominal one, with the nominal relationship given by the Ranking variable.

I can make one that's ordered alphabetically by the names of the descriptors like this:

```
edtable <- table(SourceFile$Edibility)
par(mai=c(3,1,1,1))
barplot(edtable, las=2)
```

or by frequency like this:

```
edtable <- table(SourceFile$Edibility)
par(mai=c(3,1,1,1))
barplot(edtable [order(edtable, decreasing = T)], las=2)
```

but I can't find a way to order the same sort of thing by the numerical rank.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

mytable = df[, .N, keyby = .(EdibilityRank, Edibility)]
ggplot(mytable, aes(Edibility, N )) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Thanks, Henk!  This is more of what I was looking for originally. I'll have to see how each approach works with the bigger dataset.

Comment: So actually, the line
`mytable = df[, .N, keyby = .(EdibilityRank, Edibility)]`
is giving me the error
`unused argument (keyby = .(EdibilityRank, Edibility))`
I've installed data.frame 1.9.6, so I'm expecting that the version isn't the problem. I'm using it with my original dataset, since Peter's "mushrooms" dataframe doesn't have the column EdibilityRank.

Answer (score 1):

You have redundant information in your source data, which is a bad idea as it can lead to data entry problems (eg if Edibility and EdibilityRank contradict eachother).  There are several better approaches, but one is just to use R's factor() class.  ggplot2 follows the order that the 'levels =' are defined when you create it as a factor.  See below with incomplete data.

```
library(ggplot2)

mushrooms <- data.frame(SpeciesName = c("abruptibulbus", "arvensios", "boisbisporus", "bitorquis", "campestris", "diminutivus", "fuscofibrillosus", "placomyces"),
                  Edibility = factor(c("Good", "Choice", "Good", "Choice", "Choice", "Presumed harmless", "Choice non-standard", "Mildly poisonous"), 
                                 levels = c("Choice", "Choice non-standard", "Good", "Presumed harmless", "Mildly poisonous")))

ggplot(mushrooms, aes(x = Edibility)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

If you're reading your data in from a text file or something (you don't specify), read.csv will automatically turn Edibility into a factor unless you have specified `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`; but it will default to factor levels being in alphabetical order.  In which case you need to specify them eg by

```
mushrooms$Edibility <- factor(mushrooms$Edibility, levels = c(my ordered vector here))
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter!  
  The edibility ranks are from a relational table, so there's no danger of them being mismatched. And being relational keys, it was hard to let go of them! :-) But you're right -- this is much more of the R way of doing it: using R's (sort of) mini-relational keys (factors)

Comment: sounds like you're taking it from a database, so you can be sure it will work.  Depending how complex your data is you might want to take a different approach to what I set above eg one that programmatically works out the order of the factor levels, rather than keys them in.  But if it's only half a dozen or so, probably easy to do it my way (just look out for NAs that mean you mis-typed one).

Comment: Also, it's not just that factors are R's way (awkward in my opinion) of handling a fact-table to dimension-table join, they are the way ggplot2 seems to work.  Definitely best to have factors, with carefully controlled levels, in specifying the order things appear in ggplots.